# Quiero agregar texto extra a un option con el metodo helper collection_select de rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Mi código es el siguiente y quiero asignarle más texto al `option` aparte del que le asigna el método `full_name`:

```
<%= f.collection_select(:routine, :trainer_id, @trainers, :id, :full_name, { include_blank: true },{ data: { toggle: 'update-routine-trainer' } }) %>
```

El método `collection_select` es el siguiente pero no me dice como agregar texto extra aparte del que le asigna con el parámetro `text_method`:

```
collection_select(object, method, collection, value_method, text_method, options = {}, html_options = {})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías lograrlo utilizando el método `select` en lugar de `collection_select`, lo que te dará oportunidad de asignar las opciones con un arreglo, mismo que generarías con el texto que quieres ver; por ejemplo:

```
 <%= f.select(:trainer_id,
              @trainers.map { |t| ["#{t.full_name} texto adicional" , t.id] }, 
              {include_blank: true},
              { data: { toggle: 'update-routine-trainer' } }) %>
```

Este código crea un arreglo (i.e. `@trainers.map`) con las opciones anexando el texto `texto adicional` a `full_name`.

---

Esta solución es la más directa, considerando que únicamente necesitas modificar una línea en la vista, sin embargo hay más opciones (generalmente más limpias/elegantes) donde la vista únicamente recibe el arreglo ya definido (en lugar de definirlo en la vista); esto puede ser en el modelo, en un *helper* u otros objetos como *Presentadores*. La mejor opción dependerá de la lógica y uso específico.